# Javascript - looking for an alternative to prependTo so that it doesn't add multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code. When it runs correctly, I create a success message and use prependTo in order to display it on the screen. The problem is that when the user does their successful action twice, I end up with two success messages.

Is there a way to overwrite my success message.  Here is how I currently handle it in my code:

```
  $((is_error ? "<p class=' alert alert-error'>"+message+"</p>)" : "<p class=' alert alert-success'>"+message+"</p>")).prependTo("#feedback-container");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of creating the element every time, why not just change the content/visibility of an element that already exists?

Comment: Good point. The suggestions that were made worked. I am just waiitng for SO to let me accept one of the answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simply this :

```
$("#feedback-container").html((is_error ? "<p class=' alert alert-error'>"+message+"</p>)" : "<p class=' alert alert-success'>"+message+"</p>"));
```

So the entire content of your container is replaced.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `prependTo` you can use `html`, so you would not prepend but replace contents of your message container:

```
$("#feedback-container").html(is_error ? "<p class=' alert alert-error'>"+message+"</p>" : "<p class=' alert alert-success'>"+message+"</p>");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#feedback-container").children(".alert:first-child").remove().end().prepend( "stuff" );
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/uVVYN/

Answer (score 1):

By definition prependTo will "inserted at the beginning of the element(s) specified by this parameter." In other words, it will **insert** but not **replace**.

What you are looking for is most likely the **html** method that will set the innerHTML of the matched element with the given content: http://api.jquery.com/html/

The usage of **html()** is slightly different to **prependTo()** but conceptually the same:

```
 $("#feedback-container").html((is_error ? "<p class=' alert alert-error'>"+message+"</p>)" : "<p class=' alert alert-success'>"+message+"</p>"));
```